# If a parent view has a subview as a retained property, will it be retained if removed from its superview?

Tags: ios, objective-c

retaining and adding as subview by the same superview should ideally increase the retain count by 2.
So just a call from removeFromSuperView wont ensure, the view going out of memory.

Am I right ?

Comment: yes. simple rule is if you allocate something its your responsiblity to release it.(In non-arc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you addSubview, and retain it as well, removeFromSuperview won't get it deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

you should release what you retain, should not care about other counting reference by other function exept -init or copy.

in your case , you should not care about  whether "addSubview"  will retain the view or not , then you don't need to call "removeFromSuperView " explicitly.